# Reading from a CSV file and trying to load the Data into a Vector composed of Structs?

Tags: c++, csv

I have a .csv file named "Sample.csv" that looks like this

```
0 60
1 61
2 62
3 63
```

I'm trying to read the first column as hours (int) and the second column as the temperature (double).
I have the hours and temperature set up as a struct called "Reading" and have a vector made up of these readings called "temps". 
When I run my program, it doesn't return anything and the size of temps is 0.

I know that the csv file is being read because my error message doesn't pop up and in playing around with it I got it to return "0 ,0" once.

```
struct Reading {
    int hour;
    double temperature;
};

vector<Reading> temps;
int main() {
    int hour;
    double temperature;
    ifstream ist("Sample.csv");
    if (!ist) {
        cerr << "Unable to open file data file";
        exit(1);   // call system to stop
    }
    while (ist >> hour >> temperature) {
        if(hour < 0 || 23 < hour) error("hour out of range");
        temps.push_back(Reading{hour,temperature});
    }
    for (int i=0;i<temps.size();++i){
        cout<<temps[i].hour<<", "<<temps[i].temperature<<endl;
    }
    cout<<temps.size();
    ist.close();
}
```

I was expecting:

```
0, 60
1, 61
2, 62
3, 63 
4
```

My actual output was:

```
0
```

Comment: Please post compilable code.

Comment: My best guess is that the problem is the encoding of your test file. Make sure its ascii.

Answer (score 0):

By correcting the positioning of a couple of your parenthesis, the code produces your expected result:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cerrno>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Reading {
    int hour;
    double temperature;
};

vector<Reading> temps;

int main()
{
  int hour;
  double temperature;
  ifstream ist("Sample.csv");
  if (!ist) {
    cerr << "Unable to open file data file";
    exit(1);   // call system to stop
  }
  while (ist >> hour >> temperature) {
    if (hour < 0 || 23 < hour) {
      std::cout << "error: hour out of range";
    } else {
      temps.push_back(Reading{hour, temperature});
    }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < temps.size(); ++i) {
    cout << temps[i].hour << ", " << temps[i].temperature << endl;
  }
  cout << temps.size();
  ist.close();
}
```

Output

```
0, 60
1, 61
2, 62
3, 63
4
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: `By correcting the positioning of a couple of your parenthesis` I only see the `else {}` part which is correct but it shouldn't really make any difference in this test case (since all hours are valid). Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm still receiving just 0. I'm going to check again if the file was read and opened correctly. That's the only thing I can think of at this point. I'll get back to you tomorrow. Appreciate the comment!